# how to combine queryset in django listview

Tags: django, django-models

I was using `products.objects.all()` to display all the values in the database but I want to do something more. I want to filter some specific data from the database using `products.objects.filter()`it worked but it is not working when I use this query in listview

```
coordinates = [1231,1231]
for i in coordinates:
   queryset = products.objects.filter(lat=i)
```

This code is returning only one value instead of multiple Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of for loop you should use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup to filter by multiple values:

```
queryset = products.objects.filter(lat__in=coordinates)
```